# Delete method with vue-tags-input Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to create a delete method in vue-tags-input in Vue Js. I am not sure how to get the index. from this tag. Usually in my delete method I use the index .

```
<vue-tags-input
    v-model="tagName"
    class="tags-input w-100 mt-0"
    @before-deleting-tag="deleteCustomerName"
    />

deleteCustomerName: function () {
    const id = this.editedItemId;
    const id_c = 33;  //right now I am not sure how to get id_c 

    // const deleted_user_name = this.customer_names[index].name;
    this.boxOne = "";
    this.$bvModal
        .msgBoxConfirm("Are you sure that you want to delete this ?", {
            okVariant: "danger",
            okTitle: "Delete",
            cancelTitle: "Cancel",
            centered: true
        })
        .then(confirm => {
            if (confirm) {
                deleteApi("/customers/" + id + "/" + id_c).then(() => {
                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                        // this.$emit('deleted',deleted_user_name)
                        // this.customer_names.splice(index, 1);  //usualy I do this, but now it doesn't now how index is
                        console.log('User deleted!');
                    });
                });
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is describing http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/api/events . before-deleting-tag return `index,tag,deleteTag[func]` so you need to set param in `deleteCustomerName` parameters scope .

```
deleteCustomerName: function (params) {
   console.log(params.index) 
   ....
}
```